# Why do I need to run bundle install after I reformatted my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm very new to ruby on rails which is why I'm trying to get a basic understanding of how it works. I have just created my very first rails app which is located in my dropbox folder. As I reformatted my computer two questions arise.

1) I had to do bundle install again in order to launch my local server. Why is that?

2) Also, prior to reformatting, I did cmd+p in sublime to search for files. However, files within gems didn't show in the results - now they do.

Everything works just as it did before I reformatted, I'm just trying to understand those two elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, normally you install your gems under the folder ~/.rvm, so that's likely why you needed to bundle install as that folder was removed when formatting. What makes me wonder though, 'files within gems', how do you mean? Where's that folder?

Comment: On another note, wouldn't you be better putting your files on a local drive and syncing with GitHub (or other repository)? That'll give you something else to practice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gem are not stored within your project.
If you are using RVM to maintain ruby version then gems are stored within that rvm folder.
As you have formatted your PC, it has removed gem folder from your system.
So, it is requesting for "bundle install".

This command will installing gems listed in applications GEMFILE.
If gem are already present in gem folder then it just use it for your project.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense to me now. This leads me to believe that I did something 'wrong' when I reinstalled rails, because my gems are now stored within the project. How do I revert that?

Comment: I followed this tutorial when installing rails: http://createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-with-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 0):

Gems that you require in your project are not stored in your project they are normally stored in a gems folder within your ruby install folder which would be on your local drive.

If for instance your start a new rails project you would see when you run bundle install every gem it checks for would already be installed becasue it's looking into the local gems folder.